# Как убрать консольное окно при использовании функции System?

Tags: c++, c, консоль, fortran

Добрый день, уважаемые пользователи форума!

В Fortran-е, как и в C, есть функция System, которая передает команду командной строке, при этом на экране на мгновение появляется консольное окно (Сама программа работает без использования консоли - заранее прописано:
 #pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup") ).

Собственно, вопрос в том, можно ли как-нибудь предотвратить появление этой консоли при использовании функции System?

Заранее благодарю за ответы!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не используйте функцию `system`.
Используйте `popen` или `CreateProcess`, или другую функцию, которая предоставит создаваемому процессу поток вывода, так что ОС не придется создавать консоль для этого процесса.

Comment: Благодарю, буду разбираться в этих функциях.